# extract headers from a list of files along with the file name

Tags: bash, shell-script

I was trying to write a shell script wherein I can extract the headers and also the filename from a list of files in a given directory.

For example: `ABC_TESTFILE1.csv` contains headers like

```
C1,C2,C3
```

`ABC_TESTFILE2.csv` contains headers like

```
C1,C4,C5
```

I want output text file as:

```
ABC_TESTFILE1,C1,C2,C3
ABC_TESTFILE2,C1,C4,C5
```

I was trying my luck as:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Go to where the files are located
filedir=/home/vikrant_singh_rana/AAA_USP/Combined-Files/*

for filepath in $filedir
do
 #echo "Processing $filename"
 # do something on $f
 var_head=$(head -n 1 basename "$filepath" )
 echo "$var_head"
done; > test.txt
```

Comment: You question contains a headline "!/bin/bash" without any text in that section. Something seems to be messed up here. Please fix.

Comment: have corrected that. Thanks

Comment: Beware: on the last line of your script that ";" means that the `>test.txt` is a separate command, so you are not writing into the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `printf` to format the output of `basename` and `head`:

```
for file in /home/vikrant_singh_rana/AAA_USP/Combined-Files/*.csv; do
  printf '%s,%s\n' "$(basename "$file" ".csv")" "$(head -n1 "$file")"
done >test.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a ton :-)

Answer (score 2):

Using AWK:

```
awk 'NR==1 {print FILENAME "," $0}' *.csv
```

will list all the files with a `.csv` extension containing at least one line, with the first line.

Comment: Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
path=(`ls -d /tmp/*.csv`)
        for file in "${path[@]}"; do
            head_line=`head -n1 $file`
            file_no_extension=`basename $file | sed 's/\..*//'`
            echo "$file_no_extension""$head_line"
        done
```

Make sure that path its an array:

```
[root@mole tmp]# set | grep ^path=
path=([0]="/tmp/ABC_TESTFILE1.csv" [1]="/tmp/ABC_TESTFILE2.csv")
```